# domain forwarding and seo

Tags: seo, dns, forwarding

I want http://mynewdomain.com to forward with masking to http://mysecretdomain.com/mynewsite. When a user types in http://mynewdomain.com/aboutus.html, he should see the contents of http://mysecretdomain.com/mynewsite/aboutus.html.

I do not want the public to be aware of http://mysecretdomain.com.

Will the way I use forwarding and masking negatively affect SEO?

By using domain forward and masking, is there any danger of people becoming aware of mysecretdomain.com? (ie. will users discover the relationship between mynewdomain.com and mysecretdomain.com?)

### Additional details

It is extremely important that no one discover the http://mysecretdomain.com/mynewsite domain and directory despite the fact that it is hosting all the content.  Do I have to do anything to ensure this?

Comment: What control panel are you using, plesk, cpanel, whm?

Comment: mynewdomain.com is registered with netfirms.ca and they have their own controlpanel. mysecredomain.com is registered with bluehost and it uses cpanel

Answer (score 1):

Why not just map your secret domain to the ~/www directory on your host, and the new domain to ~/www/newdomain? Then when you go to mysecretdomain.com/newdomain/ it looks in ~/www/newdomain/... exactly what you described, with no redirects.

Maybe I don't understand your goal here.

Comment: Can I do that if mysecretdomain.com and mynewdomain.com are registered with two different webhost providers?  Someone said it might involve switching nameserver information, but most providers prohibit that if the new nameservers are not on the network??  I'm so lost....

Comment: Both domains must be hosted by the same provider for this to work. If you've registered a domain with a different host, but you want to switch, you need to change the nameservers.